# Send email from my custom module

Tags: magento2, email

I have my custom module on Magento 2.3 and my custom module should send email from frontend. 
On this code, the module stops working

> ```
>             $transportToStore = $this->transportBuilder
>                 ->setTemplateIdentifier('send_pro_email_store_template')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Defin Variable `protected $_transportBuilder;`

In `__construct` Define `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder`

And Define `$this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;`

**In Your File :-**

```
protected $_transportBuilder;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    array $data = []
   ){
      $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
      parent::__construct($data);
   }

   public function yourFunction()
   {
      $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('send_pro_email_store_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->addBcc($bcc)
                ->getTransport();
      $transport->sendMessage();
   }
```

Comment: yes i have defined it in constructor, and this still not work

Comment: are you using Smtp pro ? and what is version of magento ?

Comment: I using Smtp from MagePal and this send me mail when i buy something. Magento 2.3

Comment: check test mail send or not ?

Comment: yes, test mail work

Comment: attach full code.